# QSettings printout default value for specific key

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsettings

Is there a way to printout what is the default value for a specific key?

```
int v = settings.value("key", defaultValue).toInt();
qDebug() << ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSettings` object doesn't store default values associated with the keys. According to the `QSettings::value()` function description if setting doesn't exist, the function returns the given default value - the one you already know and put as a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

QSetting is something like Dictionary that remain after closing your builded Qt project!
you will add a key and a value for it and it will be there for you for next ussage and so on!
so if you dont set value and key there is no default value for you !